# Selecting products with category name one to many relationship - using laravel 10 orm

Tags: laravel, orm

I am coding an api with laravel 10.
I want to list all products.
products table has a fk called 'category_id'
categories table has a pk called 'id'

**my product model:**

```
class Product extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = ['branch_id', 'product_category', 'product_name', 'product_slug'];

    public function productCategory() {
        return $this->belongsTo(ProductCategory::class, 'id');
    }

}
```

**my product category model**

```
class ProductCategory extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $fillable = ['branch_id', 'category_name', 'is_visible', 'display_order'];

    public function products()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Product::class, 'product_category_id', 'id');
    }

}
```

in my controller file, i have a function called "products"

```
$products = Product::with('productCategory')->get();
```

i want to see something like this;

-id - product name - product category

1. coke           drinks
2. pizza          foods

i cant get the product category name on my result output.

Answer (score 0):

Change Product model relation to this

```
    public function productCategory() {
    return $this->belongsTo(ProductCategory::class, 
    'category_id');
    }
```

Comment: still can't see "product category name" on output

Comment: is there matching records is both products and categories table ?